# Draw rectangle on HTML 5 / Javascript Teechart

Tags: javascript, html, teechart

I need to draw vertical and horizontal rectangle / bands (like in Gantt charts)  on the  HTML 5 / JavaScript Tee charts.

I could draw a rectangle using the Bar series as below but I want the rectangle to float on a particular XY cor-ordinate rather standing from the x axis.

```
var series1 = new Tee.Bar();
                     series1.data.values = [30000];
                     //alert(" openValues[y] "+ openValues[y] + " closeValues[y]  "+ closeValues[y] );
                     series1.data.x = [ (openValues[y] + closeValues[y]) /2 ];
                     series1.format.shadow.visible = false;
                     series1.format.lineCap = "round";
                     series1.format.stroke.fill = "#D3D3D3";
                     series1.format.stroke.size = .5;
                     series1.colorEach = "auto";
                     series1.format.join = "round";
                     series1.format.cap = "square";
                     series1.format.fill="#F8F8FF";
                     series1.barSize=100000;
                     //series1.format.transparent =1;
                     series1.color = "silver";
                     series1.marks.visible = false;
                     //series1.hover.shadow =false;
                     series1.hover.stroke.size =.01;
                     Chart1.addSeries(series1);
```

Is it possible to just draw a rectangle using HTML 5 / Javascript Teecharts. I want to to draw rectangles like in gantt chart with specific x1,y1,x2 and y2 values.

I tried using the Format Object in Teecharts but it didn't help

Chart1.panel.format.rectPath(20,20,30,40);

Comment: What have you tried? Question doesn't show enough effort before being asked

Comment: Currently I am using Bar Series to draw rectangle on the chart. I would like to know if there is any other elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next TeeChart Javascript v1.1 will incude the Gantt Series. Here it is the demo:
http://www.steema.us/files/jscript/demos/series/gantt/gantt.htm

We'll be glad to hear any comment about it.

Steema Support Central

Comment: I have multiple series(Line + Bar) in a chart and adding the Gannt series would not help since I want horizontal bars along the top like floating bars. When  i use the following code to draw rectangle - Chart1.panel.format.rectPath(20,20,30,40); , I get other errors within teechart. Is there a way out to solve this issue.

Comment: Another option would be using Annotation Tools with empty texts

Comment: Annotation tool did not help me since it doesn't zoom along with the chart. However Gantt series with multiple x axis solved the issue. Thanks Yeray for your support.

Answer (score 1):

To draw simple rectangle using html5...

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
  };
```

here is example link for gantt chart using html5

http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~brousse1/Libraries/RGraph/docs/gantt.html

Comment: I could do this only if I can translate between the canvas co-ordinate to the chart XY positions using Teecharts. I would like to use the TeeChart since it scales up well with  large data points

Comment: You can convert axis coordinates to pixels using the Axis calc(value) function

Comment: How do it pass the x,y values to the Axis co-ordinate?

Comment: How do I pass the X,Y values to Axis's calc function to get the co-ordinates ? can you provide example code to draw a rectangle on the chart ?

Comment: Axis calc method converts from axis scales to canvas pixel coordinates. Left and Right axis return the "Y", and Top and Bottom axis return the "X".  

  var myFormat = new Tee.Format(Chart1);
  myFormat.gradient.visible=true;
  myFormat.transparency=0.3;

  Chart1.ondraw=function() {

    var x1 = Chart1.axes.bottom.calc(4),
        y1 = Chart1.axes.left.calc(70),
        x2 = Chart1.axes.bottom.calc(7),
        y2 = Chart1.axes.left.calc(40);

    // X,Y, Width, Height
    myFormat.rectangle(x1,y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
  }